# logical OR in Java not working?

Tags: java, modulo

I am still very new to Java and I am struggling a bit trying to understand why does my code only return "false" when modulo is not equal to 0, ignoring the two other cases, so when divisor is 0 and when the array is empty.

In case of divisor = 0, I get `java.lang.ArithmeticException`: divide by zero 
For some reason empty array IS divisible by 0, how could that be?

Any help highly appreciated, thanks!

```
public boolean Divisible(ArrayList<Integer> array1, int divisor) {

    int i;
    int modulo;
    boolean isDiv=true;

    for(i=0; i<arr.size(); i++){
        modulo=((arr.get(i)%divisor));  
        i++;

        if(modulo!=0 || divisor==0 || arr.isEmpty())
        {
            isDiv= false;
            break;
        }
    } 
    return isDiv;
}
```

Comment: It is not possible to divide by 0... And executing something with given parameters and **afterwards** checking if they're correct is sort of... pointless, wouldn't you agree?

Comment: What's the point of the `arr.isEmpty()` check? If you entered the `for`, then the array is not empty.

Comment: If the List is empty, the code in the for loop never gets executed.

Comment: And you are incrementing `i` twice, once in the `for` statement and once inside the `for` block, so it will always skip one. And on top if that, it will never loop at all, because you either `break` or `return` in your first iteration already!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you do anything check for an empty List or a 0 divisor.

```
if(divisor==0||array1.isEmpty()){
    return false;
}
```

Then you can check the list.

```
for(Integer i: array1){
    if(i%divisor!=0){
        return false;
    }
}
```

Finally.

```
return true;
```

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that you're executing the OR check inside the for loop, but if the for loop iterates 0 times the condition is never checked, so the problem you're experiencing.

Here is a modified version of your function, where I moved the check conditions outside the for loop:

```
public boolean Divisible(ArrayList<Integer> array1, int divisor) 
{
    int i;
    int modulo;
    boolean isDiv = true;

    if(array1.isEmpty()) // Check array1.isEmpty() outside for loop.
    {
        isDiv = false;
    }
    else if(divisor == 0) // Check divisor outside for loop.
    {
        isDiv = false;
    }
    else
    {
        for(i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++)
        {
            modulo = (arr.get(i) % divisor); 
//          i++; i is already increased by for instruction.

            if(modulo!=0  /*|| divisor==0 || arr.isEmpty()*/) // Only modulo must be  checked here.
            {
                isDiv= false;
                break;
            }
        } 
    }

    return isDiv;
}
```